# Size of subnets

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many hosts can be supported by a subnet with a specific mask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49755/how-many-hosts-can-be-supported-by-a-subnet-with-a-specific-mask)

You are given the network 192.168.157.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 to represent your organisation. If it is decided that 3 bits are going to be "borrowed" for subnetting purposes, how many hosts can each subnet have?

need help on this question dont know how to do it

Comment: dave: your questions keep getting moved to serverfault.com. Why not post them there to begin with?

Comment: -1 please don't submit homework problems

Answer (score 1):

2 ^ 5 - 2 = 30

You have an 8 bit subnett (the last 0 in the subnett mask) 8 -3 = 5

The -2 is to remove the broadcast and subnett mask addresses

The answer is 30

Comment: should that be minus 2?  (one for the broadcast and one for the network address?)

Comment: so you mean i will have 5 hosts to each subnet

Comment: or is the network address 0? So it IS 31 as SHiraz has already said.

Comment: Dog Ears was right it should have been -2, have updated

Comment: @dave: no, the answer is 30.  although in practice you might find it's actually 29 as one of those addresses will be needed for the gateway.